# Background image - Let run image into other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would like to set [this image](https://images.pexels.com/photos/40815/youth-active-jump-happy-40815.jpeg?w=3723&h=2482&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) as an background image on [this page](https://www.pexels.com/photo/sunset-beach-people-sunrise-40815/). I would like to let the background image start on the in the class `navbar navbar-default`. And now my problem comes. I want that the image continues to the next div called

```
class="elementor-element elementor-element-gjr87i6 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section"
```

How can I implement that? - I already tried overflow but I don't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the background image to a div, and inside this div you have to put the oher divs you want to share the same background.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it wrapping both `div`'s in a common parent div and applying the background image to that parent `div`. Use jQuery `wrapAll()` function to dynamically wrap them ( assuming they are adjacent `div`'s ).

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='navbar navbar-default'></div>
  <div class='elementor-element elementor-element-gjr87i6 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-top-section'></div>
</div>

.wrap {
  background: url('...') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

$('.navbar-default, .elementor-top-section').wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>');
```

Comment: Sadly, I cannot do that because it is a wordpress webpage

Comment: @ChantelleWedel You can wrap them dynamically using jQuery. I've updated my anwer.